# Testing imported components that are rendered in a different component with Enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am doing some testing with React/Jest/Enzyme and I am just a bit stuck on how (or if I should) to test components that have been imported into a component like so:

```
import React from 'react'
import Services from './Services'
import Team from './Team'
import Customers from './Customers'


class Main extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div id="main">
                    <Services />
                    <Team />
                    <Customers />
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default Main
```

So I am looking to test Services, Team , Customers that are rendered in the Main component. Is it really best to have something like this (which I haven't checked by the way, just as a quick draft to show an example):

```
  test('Services imports and renders correctly', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <MemoryRouter>
        <Services />
      </MemoryRouter>
    );
    expect(wrapper.find(Services)).toHaveLength(1);
  });
```

Any code, tips, guidance to syntax would be super helpful!

Many thanks :)

Comment: Shouldn't have `Services`, `Team`, and `Customers` already been tested each alone in their own unit tests already? Or is that what you are asking about now, how to test them individually?

Comment: Yes they do have their own tests, but I was wondering if I should write a test for the Main component and the only obvious thing to test is that these components import and render correctly in this Main component. Or is it not even worth testing?

Comment: IMO a "should render without crashing" is a simple valid test for `Main`, but yes, there isn't much more going on *to test*.

Comment: Great thank you Drew :)